# Liquibase Gradle plugin appears to have url and referenceUrl reversed

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have a very simple Spring Boot 2.0.4 project. Following the various examples for setting up the Liquibase Gradle plugin I wanted to be able to run the `diffChangeLog` target to update my change log XML file. The configuration looks like this:

```
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            url                 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example_db'
            username            'user'
            password            'password'
            driver              'org.postgresql.Driver'

            referenceUrl        'hibernate:spring:com.example?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
            referenceDriver     'liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver'

            classpath           'src/main'
            changeLogFile       "src/main/resources/db/changelog/master.xml"
        }
        runList = 'main'
    }
}
```

The database is empty except for the `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock` tables. When I run `gradle diffChangeLog` the change log XML file is never updated. The output from `gradle diff` shows "NONE" for everything. My project does have an entity and it is annotated with `@Entity`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess your schema is generated by hibernate (or something like this); so the @Entity has no matter here

The diifChangeLog command is only looking to your database schema.

Did you try with the command line ?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: It seems that liquibase-gradle looks entities in build folder and not in sources.